# Better way to remove/hide parts from $_GET but still capture full value

Tags: php, get, flat-file

I'm working a flatfile blog style script project, the text file names are  layed out like so:

`05--im-a-title-and-may-c0ntain-lett3r5-and-numb3rs--14-12-2014`

I use `explode()` `--` to split into 3 parts for index listing

- `$id`
- `$title`
- `$date`

link to single page being `$title`

The single page code at the moment is:

```
$search = $dir . "*" . clean($_GET['title']) . "*" . '.txt';

$files = glob($search);

$getfile  = $files[0];

echo file_get_contents($getfile);
```

As you see I am using `globe()` and it's wildcards to match the `$_GET` to file name to grab the file content and to remove/hide id and date parts from url which is working fine but once the files start piling up it will also start to get very server intensive having to search many files so wanting to fix this problem before it even starts so looking for a much better way to remove/hide parts from `$_GET` whist still finding the correct file.

**Update:**
The purpose of this is to make single page url cleaner `domain.com/i-am-a-title` rather than `domain.com/05--im-a-title--14-12-2014`

**Update 2:**
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ single.php?title=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you searching file? Directly get the exact file.

Comment: It is so the url is cleaner `/i-am-a-title` rather than `/05--im-a-title--14-12-2014` and is only option that I have got to work as desired.

Comment: I think you should make a change to single page url..Like:
http://example.com/posts/5/14-12-2014/im-a-title-and-may-c0ntain-lett3r5-and-numb3rs @AnnaRiekic

Comment: You mean `$getfile  = $_GET['title'];
echo file_get_contents($getfile);` that will then show the full text file name which is not what I want.

Comment: Nope. Send all needed data like
single.php?id=5&date=14-12-2014&title=im-a-title
and if you want use htaccess to rewrite @AnnaRiekic

Comment: That is also not what I want I only want `domain.com/i-am-a-title` i already use htaccess will add to op

Comment: I think i did not understand your question fully.Are you telling that when too many file will be stored `glob()` will take more time to search file??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70000/discussion-between-istiak-tridip-and-anna-riekic).